# Initialization in scope overwrites array values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am facing a small issue. I am almost done with my functionality.

I have a form, where I have an option given to the user to submit more than one projects. This is facilitated by dynamic generation of dropdownlist after clicking on "Add More" functionality. Now there can be any number of dropdownlists generated by the user. I am catching the values in an array and sending it to the server to be saved in the database.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save()" style="margin-left:220px;">
        <table cellpadding="10">    
<tr>
                <td></td>
                <!--data-ng-repeat='item in array'-->
                <td style="width: 270px;">
                    <div>
                        <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
                            <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)" ng-model="ProjectId[item]">
                        <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0px;">
                            <li >
                                <!--data-ng-model="selectedProject[$index]"-->
                                <!--data-ng-model="test.ProjectId"-->
                                <!--<select data-ng-model="test.ProjectId" 
                                data-ng-options="test.ProjectId as test.ProjectName for test in items" id="Project">-->
                                <select>
                                    <option value="">-- Choose a Project --</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.ProjectId}}">{{item.ProjectName}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="button" ng-click="closeAlert($index)"><img src="delete.png" alt="Remove" style="height:20px; width:20px;" /></button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </alert>
                            <button class='btn' type='button' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Projects</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label id="Label2" style="color: red"></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
        <div style="margin-left: 200px;">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()" />
            <a href="#/emp" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

ALERT is the custom directive that is allowing us to generate dynamic dropdownlists onclick of "Add More"

Code for controller in app.js

```
var CreateCtrlEmp = function ($scope, $location, SampleEmp, SampleProj, SampleDes, sharedValues) {
$scope.items = SampleProj.query({ q: $scope.query });
$scope.itemsd = SampleDes.query({ q: $scope.query });
$scope.save = function () {
    //issue over here
    $scope.item.ProjectId = [];
    SampleEmp.save($scope.item);
    $location.path('/emp');
};};
```

Now I am not getting the selected values in the server side code. The possible problems are:

1. The code is not able to send the values to the server side code i.e. it is passing an empty array.
2. The initialization of $scope.item.ProjectId = []; is ovrewriting the posted values and due to that I am getting the empty array.

Note: When I am passing static values in the controller like:

$scope.item.ProjectId = [5,7];

The functionaity is working properly.

Please guide.

Thanx a ton!

Tushar Sharma

Comment: hmm are you submiting using ng-submit? If you execute the save() function on submit it looks to me like you reset the array each time and therefore sending just an empty array. Please show how the form tags aswell. Also, you shouldent use value="" .. ever when doing angular, let the model do what it's supposed to.

Comment: Theres the form tag. I am using ng-submit. So what alternative should we use then?

Comment: And talking about the value="" thing. I donot have other option, because we want the data transfers to take place using the projectid values. So I have to take it. It is required as we are having the curly syntax interpolation to populate the dropdownlist.

Comment: Look at my answer. If you do that you will send the selected projectId when doing what I suggest

Answer (score 0):

You should store the selected value in the model and send the model with the ng-submit. I also do not recommend using ng-repeat populating options in a select tag.  Remember that ng-model equals value="". Whats in the model is whats getting sent. You also use the model if you want to preselect something when the view loads.

Do something like this ( miniversion of your example ):

## Template

```
<form name="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save(myForm)" style="margin-left:220px;">

    <table cellpadding="10">    
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 270px;">
                <div>
                    <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
                        <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)" ng-model="ProjectId[item]">
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0px;">
                        <li >
                            <!--data-ng-model="selectedProject[$index]"-->
                            <!--data-ng-model="test.ProjectId"-->
                            <!--<select data-ng-model="test.ProjectId" data-ng-options="test.ProjectId as test.ProjectName for test in items" id="Project">-->
                            <select ng-model="myForm.project" ng-options="test.ProjectId as test.ProjectName for test in items">
                                <option>-- Choose a Project --</option>
                            </select>
                        <li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    
</form>
```

## Controller

```
$scope.save = function (myForm) {
    SampleEmp.save(myForm);
    $location.path('/emp');
};
```

Comment: I used this technique but nothing is getting passsed. Not even the older data that was getting passed. So what you are doing basically is storing the data as properties of an object named myForm. Right?

Comment: Yes, everything that is selected in the form that uses "myForm" as a prefix will be sent on submit, now since its only 1 input only that will be sent. Inside SampleEmp.save(myForm) you will access your projectId by using "myForm.project". I sugest that you console.log(myForm) inside $scope.save() to see what it contains when it gets that far.

Comment: Ok. But I basically want to send an array of values i.e. an array of projectIds. So what do we do in that case. And yes would this work fine when I would want to load these values back in the textboxes during the edit employee mode?

Comment: Ehm ok maybe I missunderstood you a little bit. Is your intention to be able to choose from the dropdown list, X times and then send the selected projectId's(array) to the API?

Comment: Okay..let me explain it. In the system. There can be n number of dropdownlists. So every dropdown wil have one selection.Hence there will be n numbre of selected values to be sent to the server to be saved. So I want all those n values to be stored in the array and sent to the server. Got a bit of idea?

Comment: Aight I dont see the whole picture unless you paste more of your code but in theorie you can generate the droplists with dynamic models like myForm.project<x> and then you send myForm and all selects will follow. In the API you will have to parse the key,val to extract the selected values

Comment: I have already generated the dropdownlists. I just need to send the selected values in the array ProjectId[item] to the controller, which can save the data. So it would be great if you would help me to send only the ProjectIds to the server. We donot need to send the ProjectName

Comment: You can execute a function using ng-change="addToArray(myForm.project)" and handle that in the controller but I wouldent recommend it due inconsistency. Do what I suggested earlier using myForm.project<x> and post "myForm" when your done. That will help you keep track of each choice in each dropdown, instead of handling id's that dont belong aywere in an array. I will end this discussion now. If my solution isnt what your looking for you need to wait for someone else to respond.

Comment: Thanx @JoakimB for your help. But could you explain it in a bit more detail. Or some link for the same.?